# Get the index of the group that matched in a regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, indexing, match, regex-group

I have a regexp:

```
/(alpha)|(beta)|(gamma)/gi
```

Some text to match against:

```
Betamax. Digamma. Alphabet. Hebetation.
```

The matches are:

```
beta, gamma, alpha, beta
```

The values I am looking would be:

```
1,2,0,1
```

...can I ascertain the index of the group that matched in the regexp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To [access the groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432493/1048572), you will need to use [`.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) repeatedly:

```
var regex = /(alpha)|(beta)|(gamma)/gi,
    str = "Betamax. Digamma. Alphabet. Hebetation.";
for (var nums = [], match; match = regex.exec(str); )
    nums.push(match.lastIndexOf(match[0]));
```

If you want the indizes zero-based, you could use

```
    nums.push(match.slice(1).indexOf(match[0]));
```

Comment: This is my favourite so far, I love your use of manipulation of the results to get a zero-based result.

Comment: Yeah, it looks nice and allows us to use `indexOf` instead of backward search. Though, just appending `- 1` to the first one would be shorter and more performant :)

Answer (score 1):

Build your regex from an array of strings, and then lookup the matches with indexOf.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the exact sample you provided, the below will work:

```
var r = /(alpha)|(beta)|(gamma)/gi;
var s = "Betamax. Digammas. Alphabet. Habetation.";

var matched_indexes = [];
var cur_match = null;

while (cur_match = r.exec(s))
{
    matched_indexes.push(cur_match[1] ? 0 : cur_match[2] ? 1 : 2 );
}

console.log(matched_indexes);
```

I leave it to you to make the content of the loop more dynamic / generic :p